# fwrite (php) doesn't always write

Tags: php, symfony, fwrite

Using php fwrite in a symfony2's controller to write a Base64 image, the file not always has been write in the directory.
The file that i write has every time a different name,so there aren't problem for the 
rewrite of the same file.
The variable $data has already been decoded.

```
 public function convertAction(Request $request){
    $data= $request->request->get('data');
    $filen= $request->request->get('filename');
    $uploadDir = $this->container->getParameter('upload_tmp');
    $file = $uploadDir . $filen;
    $fp = fopen($file, 'wb');
    fwrite($fp, $data);
  fclose($fp);
return new Response() ; 
}
```

Comment: what is `wb` and what if you try `file_put_contents` instead

Answer (score 2):

fopen and fwrite return false in case of an error. Do you get false from one of these functions when no file is written?

Comment: Do you get an error message when you enable error reporting or is it already enabled?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
 public function convertAction(Request $request){
    $data= $request->request->get('data');
    $filen= $request->request->get('filename');
    $uploadDir = $this->container->getParameter('upload_tmp');
    $file = $uploadDir . $filen;
    $fp = fopen($file, 'w') or die ('Something went wrong'); // That show is an error ocurres The flag for read/write in binary secure mode "wb" does nothing with fopen()
    fwrite($fp, $data);
  fclose($fp);
return new Response() ; 
}
```